# How to Reduce UIImage size while uploading while taking a Photo from iPhone

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

All

I have a requirement to Upload a `UIImage` taken from Photo Gallery or Photo taken from Camera,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info  
{

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:chosenImage,@"chosenImage", nil];

UIImage* selectedImage = [userInfo objectForKey:@"chosenImage"]

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage);

}
```

I am using imageData to upload it on server, I want to know is there any way to reduce the memory size of the `UIImage` without changing the quality. Please let me know.

Comment: The following question is answered in the following [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487316/reduce-uiimage-size-to-a-manageable-size-reduce-bytes

Comment: Just noticed you mentioned without changing the quality.